Explicit linear system corresponding to rational map to $\mathbb{P}^1$
Let  $L$ be a line in $\mathbb{P}^3$. Then we can define a map
$$
\pi\colon \mathbb{P}^3 \dashrightarrow \mathbb{P}^1, \qquad x \mapsto \langle x, L \rangle \cap L'
$$
where $L'$ is a line such that $L$ and $L'$ span $\mathbb{P}^3$ and $L \cap L'=\emptyset$ and $\langle x, L\rangle$ is the span of $x$ and $L$ in $\mathbb{P}^3$.
This map is not defined on $L \subset \mathbb{P}^3$, so I know that the linear system is not base-point free.
But what is the linear system of divisors corresponding to this map?
Is it the collection of preimages of $\pi$? What dimension is the linear system?
EDIT: Further question:
What is the sheaf corresponding to the linear system? I.e. how can I determine the sheaf such that the sections of the sheaf give the morphism to $\mathbb{P}^1$?

This is the pencil of hyperplanes containing $L$.

So the fibres of the map $\pi$?

The sheaf is $I_L(1)$, the ideal of $L$ twisted by $\mathcal{O}(1)$.

@Sasha, how can I see that?

For instance, you can choose coordinates $(x_0:\dots:x_3)$ such that the line $L$ is given by $x_0 = x_1 = 0$. Then you map is given by $$(x_0:\dots:x_3) \mapsto (x_0:x_1),$$ hence your sheaf is the image of the map $\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}(1)$ given by $(x_0,x_1)$.  The rest is clear.

Why does the map $(x_0:\cdots :x_3) \mapsto (x_0:x_1)$ imply that the sheaf is the image of $\mathcal{O}\oplus \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}(1)$?

By its definition.

I still don't understand why $\mathcal{O}(1)$ plays a role (perhaps because $(x_0:x_1)$ might not be well-defined?). Also, why $I_L(1)$ is the image of $\mathcal{O} \oplus \mathcal{O} \to \mathcal{O}(1)$ is not clear to me.
